# C++ unordered_map::at() and operator[ ] doesn't behave the same

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map

I have the following code

```
  unordered_map<unique_ptr<Test>, int> _unordered_map;
  Test* _test1 = new Test;
  unique_ptr<Test> _ptr0(_test1);
  unique_ptr<Test> _ptr1(new Test);

 _unordered_map.insert(make_pair( std::move(_ptr0), 1  ));
 _unordered_map.insert(make_pair( std::move(_ptr1), 1  ));

  unique_ptr<Test> _ptr3(_test1);
  cout <<  _unordered_map.at(_ptr3);
```

gcc gives compilation error if I change the last line to

```
cout <<  _unordered_map[_ptr3];
```

Shouldn't the operator[] and at() of unordered_map behave the same ?

Comment: No, they shouldn't, because they are different functions. But **what** error? "GCC gives compilation error" is not helpful, we are not mind readers.

Answer (score 4):

> Shouldn't the `operator[]` and `at()` of `unordered_map` behave the same ?

No. If the key isn't found, then `at` will throw an exception, while `[]` will insert a new element with that key. In order to do that, the supplied key must be copyable or movable; your key type isn't copyable, and is only movable if passed as an *rvalue*. So this should compile:

```
cout << _unordered_map[std::move(_ptr3)];
```

Of course, there's little point using `[]` or `at`, since you can't make a non-empty `unique_ptr` that will compare equal to any in the map (unless, as in your example, you create two `unique_ptr`s owning the same object, which will be disastrous).